# How can i match the request in jmeter. both should be identical of each other

Tags: jmeter, pattern-matching

My Scenario is:
When i need to create a user for my project. when i create a user, on that page there are some default setting which should be same as default setting page where i have set some settings that will be applicable on all users.

I want to match that default settings should be same as newely created user's detail page settings.

For this scenario, what should be the solution. Default setting page is dynamic. we can change the settings on this page any time so everytime user's page settings should be same as defaults settings page.

Comment: I read 3 times, still i dont understand the question :(

Comment: @vins I think op means they have a form and something (presumably JS) which sets form's field values to "defaults". They want to have the same defaults in JMeter. But of course without further details, not possible to say anything.